# Does Outlook Redemption support .Net core?

Tags: .net-core, outlook-redemption

We are already using "Redemption.dll"(http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) in one application developed in VB.Net. Now we need to use Redemption to create PST file for Linux environment.

So, can we use Redemption in .Net Core (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) application or with JAVA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Redemption depends on the MAPI system to be present. The MAPI system is only installed by Outlook. You can also install the standalone version of MAPI, but it is no longer supported by MS. Windows is required in both cases of course.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any API in your knowledge, which can be used on Linux system to create PST Files in Java or any other Linux supported programming language?

Comment: I know there are some libraries that can process PST file, but I have never used them, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, most of the JAVA supported API only read/parse PST files but cannot help to create PST file. Can you suggest some JAVA or Linux system compatible APIs, that can help to create PST files? Thank you in Advance!

Comment: I am not aware of any, sorry.